# Refresh (or change) background image dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I'd appreciate any help with this.

What I need to do is refresh/change the background image of a live chart, every time that I add some data to it. The live data part works fine.

I've tried the "chart.plotBGImage.attr({href: 'xxx'});" approach but I get an error: "Cannot read property 'plotBGImage' of undefined".

Any ideas on what's wrong or for a diffrent approach?

Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart1; 

    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_data/getECGdata.php',
            success: function(point) {

                var series1 = chart1.series[0],
                shift = series1.data.length > 20; 

                // add the point
                chart1.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);    


                //The line below is the one giving the error
                //this.chart1.plotBGImage.attr({href: "http://www.highcharts.com/images/stories/logohighcharts.png"});              

                // call it again after one/two/etc seconds
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
                },
            cache: false
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                zoomType: 'x',
                backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                marginTop: 60,
                events: {load: requestData}
            },
            title: {text: 'Live ECG data'},
            xAxis: {type: 'datetime', tickPixelInterval: 150, maxZoom: 20 * 1000},
            yAxis: {minPadding: 0.2, maxPadding: 0.2, title: {text:'ECG reading', margin: 20 } },
            tooltip: {xDateFormat: '%H:%M:%S', shared: true},
            credits: {enabled: false},
            series: [
                    {name: 'ECG', color: 'green', data: [] }

                ]
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: chart.plotBGImage.attr({href: 'xxx'}) works, only one thing - your variable name is chart1, not chart.. And to change plot background, firstly you need to have at chart initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that u are trying to change the background image in the Highchart.

Just giving `chart.plotBGImage.attr({href: 'xxx'});` will not help, u will need to reload the entire HighChart.

I did this (without the Live Data part as its working fine for you!!) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/JgQEc/1/)

Comment: Thanks lshank, I got it working the way you suggested :-) 

The only drawback is a new to reload the chart every time, but I guess there's no way around that. The other solution is to do what Sebastian suggested and change the css properties of the chart's container.

Comment: glad if it helped:) may need to use `.destroy();` at a suitable place before reloading the chart so as to make sure memory is preserved..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I changed the background image of my chart:
Download any pattern and put it in your image folder, now simply add the following code in your highchart:

```
  chart: {  
    plotBackgroundImage:'/assets/lightpaperfibers.png',
  },
```

Write the name of image in the paths i.e. '/assets/your_image.png'

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
chart.highcharts().plotBGImage.attr({href: picturePath});
```

allows to change the image on the chart. I changes the image after click the button, so this works.
In my project `picturePath` was the path to a folder with a picture: "Pictures/example.png"

The exact code:

```
self.chartPlot = chart.highcharts();
...
self.pic = ...;
self.chartPlot.plotBGImage.attr({href: self.pic});// changes the image on the chart.
```

Now (Nov 2014) I'm working on my project www.tanks-vs.com with actively using Highcharts and also this command. So after 1 or 2 weeks it will be implemented there, you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable stanrdard bacrkgoudn color by:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
```

Then set backgorund in CSS for #contaniner and use jquery / javacript to modify it.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/LGzuj/

Comment: Thanks for this!
However, is it not possible to change just the background image?